# Binding Picker ItemSource to List<string> not working Xamarin.forms MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding

Firstly I'm retrieving an array from firebase cloud firestore. It's an array of strings. I then add those strings to a List. The issue is when I try to bind the pickers ItemSource to the list of strings it doesn't show the results when I click on the picker (its just blank). Please help me out here, I cannot seem to find a solution. Code below:

In the ViewModel (parts relevant):

```
public ObservableCollection<string> NamesListObsv { get; set; }

private List<string> _namesList;
public List<string> NamesList
    {
        get
        {
            return _namesList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_namesList != value)
            {
                _namesList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

NamesList = await GetNamesAsync();

NamesListObsv = new ObservableCollection<string>(NamesList);

public async Task<List<string>> GetNamesAsync()
    {
        try
        {

            var namesDoc = await CrossCloudFirestore.Current
                                                         .Instance
                                                         .Collection("names")
                                                         .Document("names_list")
                                                         .GetAsync();


            var namesList = namesDoc.ToObject<NamesModel>().NamesList;

            List<string> tempList = new List<string>();

            foreach (var names in namesList)
            {
                tempList.Add(name.ToString());
            }

            return tempList;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return null;
        }          
    }
```

The Model:

```
public class NamesModel
{
    [Id]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [MapTo("name_array")]
    public List<string> NamesList { get; set; }

}
```

The XAML (parts relevant):

```
<Picker x:Name="NamesListPicker"
                            Title="Select your Name.."
                            ItemsSource="{Binding NamesListObsv}"
                            ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding .}"/>
```

Yet all I get is an empty Picker even though the NamesListObsv contains three names ([0] "bob" [1] "jim" [2] "john"). Any advice would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried ObservableCollection?

Comment: There's no `OnPropertyChanged();` in the setter of `NamesListObsv`. That's why.

Comment: first, are you sure that `NamesListObsv` contains data?  Second, I don't believe that you need `ItemDisplayBinding` if the data is just `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw away NamesList and refactor NamesListObsv  to:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _namesListObsv;
public ObservableCollection<string> NamesListObsv 
    {
        get
        {
            return _namesListObsv;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_namesListObsv!= value)
            {
                _namesListObsv= value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }


NamesListObsv = new ObservableCollection<string>(await GetNamesAsync());
```

Answer (score 0):

> Yet all I get is an empty Picker even though the NamesListObsv contains three names ([0] "bob" [1] "jim" [2] "john").

Don't use `NamesListObsv = new ObservableCollection<string>(NamesList);`, try to foreach NamesList to add data into NamesListObsv.

```
   NamesListObsv = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for(int i=0;i<NamesList.Count;i++)
        {
            NamesListObsv.Add(NamesList[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Thankyou for the advice :)  I went with lidqy's answer as it seemed to be the cleanest + simplest option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure, `GetNamesAsync()` returns data
2. Make sure, your ViewModel implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface
3. Make sure, when you are assigning value to the variable named `NamesListObsv` the `PropertyChanged` event gets triggered.

As far as I see, you do not have Notify to the user interface, when the `NamesListObsv` gets a value.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at this issue. 1. It does return data correctly. 2. The vm does implement PropertyChanged(). 3. I wasn't notifying which seemed to be the problem, I accepted lidqy's answer as it addressed the issue perfectly :).